# How to remove spy-ware and how to turn off GPS-Tracking?

Tags: malware

Someone installed spy-ware and is also tracking my GPS.  I can tell because when I open navigator the location is not where I am. I have driven to the location and someone is sitting in their car.  This same person follows me around town. also when I call my daughter a third party answers phone also so I can't get through to my daughter.I have tried factory reset but the person is still in control of my GPS.  How do I get control back on my phone?

Comment: If you're sure about this, go to the police.  You can install an antivirus app from the Play Store to try to root out malware.

Comment: In addition to that, consider changing your phone if the issue is irreparable.

Answer (score 1):

I mean this in the nicest possible way but do you have problems with paranoia....that is the most logical explanation for what you're reporting in my opinion. Otherwise what you're saying doesn't make much sense - why would someone targeting you alter your gps to show their location as your location... That would just lead you to them... Also if your gps just shows that incorrect location as your location then it doesn't seem to be tracking you. Please consider seeking help.